# iftop bandwidth monitor shows rates=0 (but do show connected hosts) on tun0 (ppp)

Tags: monitoring, freebsd, bandwidth

On my FreeBSD box, working as my LAN's router, I tried using `iftop` (from `ports/net-mgmt`) to monitor bandwidth usage. The program works well for monitoring the server's LAN interface-card, but not for the `tun0` virtual/loopback interface created by `ppp`. It does show connected internet-hosts, but no traffic is shown (upload and download rates all show **0 b/s**). The host-list is refreshed with new hosts (though a bit slowly), but other than that nothing happens. `top` shows WCPU-usage > 100% for `iftop`. Pressing `Q` or `Ctrl-C` for quitting takes forever (>10 secs).

What causes this, and are there any solutions to get `iftop` to work for my `tun0` interface?

I'm open towards other programs (preferably a program included in the FreeBSD ports-collection), but would like a terminal-program (ncurses or something) that resembles `iftop` by representing outgoing+incoming traffic for each connected host as ASCII-graphs. Any suggestions for such programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any solution to my `iftop` issue, but I found some useful alternatives that does almost the same (although none with per-host usage-graphs). While it seems `iftop` has to be monitoring the `tun0` interface (otherwise it won't show any connected hosts), some of the others (`pktstat`, for instance) should be set up to monitor the underlying physical WAN-interface (`em1` in my case).

Alternatives include (but are almost certainly not limited to) these programs, all in the FreeBSD ports collection, and all run in the terminal:

- pktstat (I find these args useful: `pktstat -P -t -n -B -i em1`)
- bmon (shows usage graph for each interface over time)
- trafshow
- bwm-ng

I found these from [this site](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu-users.html), where there are screenshots of each program.